# What is the solid shape of this function?

Tags: calculus

What is the solid shape of the function? I know the answer is 0 by integrating but I have to do it using without
[image: question]

Comment: One way of thinking about this is to consider on what curves within $[0,r]^2$ the function $r-x-y$ is constant; in particular, where it's zero.  Drawing these 'topographical' level lines will help you get a sense for the shape.

Comment: If cant solve it,at least learn type it in Mathjax instead of a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the union of two right triangular pyramid whose bases are right angled triangles of sides $r$,$r$,$\sqrt{2}r$ lying on the $xy$-plane. One pyramid is pointing upward with height $r$ (apex at $(0,0,r)$). The other one is pointing downward with height $r$ too (apex at $(r,r,−r)$). They have same volume but the signed volume of second pyramid is negative. So their total signed volume (which equals to the integral) is zero.

[image: An union of two pyramid]